# How can I make all the items in the menu sticky?

Tags: html, css, menu

I am trying to add a menu bar to my website and it looks nearly the way I want it, with the hamburger to the left and the two contact info to the right. However, only the hamburger is sticky. Also, I would like to add a background color to the menu so that when the webpage is scrolled the sticky bits sit neatly inside the colored bar. How can I make these changes?

```css
nav {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0px;
  /* make it look decent enough */
  background: #232323;
  color: #cdcdcd;
  font-family: inherit;
}

#menuToggle {
  display: inline-block;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
  z-index: 1;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

#menuToggle a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #232323;
  transition: color 0.3s ease;
}

#menuToggle a:hover {
  color: yellowgreen;
}

#menuToggle input {
  display: block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 32px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -7px;
  left: -5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0;
  /* hide this */
  z-index: 2;
  /* and place it over the hamburger */
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
}


/*
       * Just a quick hamburger
       */

#menuToggle span {
  display: block;
  width: 33px;
  height: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  position: relative;
  background: #cdcdcd;
  border-radius: 3px;
  z-index: 1;
  transform-origin: 4px 0px;
  transition: transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0.2, 0.05, 1.0), background 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0.2, 0.05, 1.0), opacity 0.55s ease;
}

#menuToggle span:first-child {
  transform-origin: 0% 0%;
}

#menuToggle span:nth-last-child(2) {
  transform-origin: 0% 100%;
}


/* 
       * Transform all the slices of hamburger
       * into a crossmark.
       */

#menuToggle input:checked~span {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-2px, -1px);
  background: #232323;
}


/*
       * But let's hide the middle one.
       */

#menuToggle input:checked~span:nth-last-child(3) {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: rotate(0deg) scale(0.2, 0.2);
}


/*
       * Ohyeah and the last one should go the other direction
       */

#menuToggle input:checked~span:nth-last-child(2) {
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(0, -1px);
}


/*
       * Make this absolute positioned
       * at the top left of the screen
       */

#menu {
  position: absolute;
  width: 300px;
  margin: -100px 0 0 -50px;
  padding: 50px;
  padding-top: 125px;
  padding-bottom: 325px;
  background: #ededed;
  list-style-type: none;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  /* to stop flickering of text in safari */
  transform-origin: 0% 0%;
  transform: translate(-100%, 0);
  transition: transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0.2, 0.05, 1.0);
}

#menu li {
  padding: 8px 0;
  font-size: 20px;
}


/*
       * And let's slide it in from the left
       */

#menuToggle input:checked~ul {
  transform: none;
}


/* header-right  */

.header-right li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 50px;
  margin-top: 45px;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  float: right;
  font-family: inherit;
  -webkit-transition: .5s;
  -moz-transition: .5s;
  -ms-transition: .5s;
  -o-transition: .5s;
  transition: .5s;
}

.header-right li i {
  margin-right: 7px;
  color: #888;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.header-right li :hover {
  color: #7370d8;
  text-decoration: none;
}


/*
       * Subscription form for newsletter
       */

.subscribe-form input[type="text"] {
  padding: 13.225px 30px;
  border: none;
  background: #f2f2f2;
  float: none;
}

.subscribe-form input[type="submit"] {
  background: #9bf55f;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 16px 24px;
  border: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  float: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
  <title>My website</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <!--[if lte IE 8]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <script src="css/ie/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery.poptrox-2.2.js"></script>
  <script src="js/skel.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/init.js"></script>
  <noscript>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/skel-noscript.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    </noscript>
  <!--[if lte IE 8]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ie/v8.css">
    <![endif]-->

</head>

<body>
  <nav role="navigation">
    <div id="menuToggle">

      <input type="checkbox" />


      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>


      <ul id="menu">
        <a href="index.html">
          <li>Home</li>
        </a>
        <a href="about-us.html">
          <li>My listings</li>
        </a>
        <a href="https://selar.co/vmo2" target="_blank">
          <li>Bookings</li>
        </a>
        <a href="faq.html">
          <li>FAQ</li>
        </a>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="header-right">
      <ul class="pull-right">
        <li>
          <a href="#">
            <i class="fa fa-phone"></i> +5558976555
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">
            <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>mylistings@gmail.com
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

New addition: Js (there's more than one of it but I think it's this one?)

```
/* poptrox 2.2 | n33.co | MIT/GPLv2 */

(function(jQuery) {

    jQuery.fn.poptrox_disableSelection = function() { return jQuery(this).css('user-select', 'none').css('-khtml-user-select', 'none').css('-moz-user-select', 'none').css('-o-user-select', 'none').css('-webkit-user-select', 'none'); }

    jQuery.fn.poptrox = function(options) {

        // Settings

            var settings = jQuery.extend({
                    preload:                        false,                          // If true, preload fullsize images in the background
                    baseZIndex:                     1000,                           // Base Z-Index
                    fadeSpeed:                      300,                            // Global fade speed
                    overlayColor:                   '#000000',                      // Overlay color
                    overlayOpacity:                 0.6,                            // Overlay opacity
                    windowMargin:                   50,                             // Window margin size (in pixels; only comes into play when an image is larger than the viewport)
                    windowHeightPad:                0,                              // Window height pad
                    selector:                       'a',                            // Anchor tag selector
                    popupSpeed:                     300,                            // Popup (resize) speed
                    popupWidth:                     200,                            // Popup width
                    popupHeight:                    100,                            // Popup height
                    popupIsFixed:                   false,                          // If true, popup won't resize to fit images
                    useBodyOverflow:                true,                           // If true, the BODY tag is set to overflow: hidden when the popup is visible
                    usePopupEasyClose:              true,                           // If true, popup can be closed by clicking on it anywhere
                    usePopupLoader:                 true,                           // If true, show the popup loader
                    usePopupCloser:                 true,                           // If true, show the popup closer button/link
                    usePopupCaption:                false,                          // If true, show the popup image caption
                    usePopupNav:                    false,                          // If true, show (and use) popup navigation
                    usePopupDefaultStyling:         true,                           // If true, default popup styling will be applied (background color, text color, etc)
                    popupBackgroundColor:           '#FFFFFF',                      // (Default Style) Popup background color (when usePopupStyling = true)
                    popupTextColor:                 '#000000',                      // (Default Style) Popup text color (when usePopupStyling = true)
                    popupLoaderTextSize:            '2em',                          // (Default Style) Popup loader text size
                    popupCloserBackgroundColor:     '#000000',                      // (Default Style) Popup closer background color (when usePopupStyling = true)
                    popupCloserTextColor:           '#FFFFFF',                      // (Default Style) Popup closer text color (when usePopupStyling = true)
                    popupCloserTextSize:            '20px',                         // (Default Style) Popup closer text size
                    popupPadding:                   10,                             // (Default Style) Popup padding (when usePopupStyling = true)
                    popupCaptionHeight:             60,                             // (Default Style) Popup height of caption area
                    popupCaptionTextSize:           null,                           // (Default Style) Popup caption text size
                    popupBlankCaptionText:          '(untitled)',                   // Applied to images that don't have captions (when captions are enabled)
                    popupCloserText:                '&#215;',                       // Popup closer text
                    popupLoaderText:                '&bull;&bull;&bull;&bull;',     // Popup loader text
                    popupClass:                     'poptrox-popup',                // Popup class
                    popupSelector:                  null,                           // (Advanced) Popup selector (use this if you want to replace the built-in popup)
                    popupLoaderSelector:            '.loader',                      // (Advanced) Popup Loader selector
                    popupCloserSelector:            '.closer',                      // (Advanced) Popup Closer selector
                    popupCaptionSelector:           '.caption',                     // (Advanced) Popup Caption selector
                    popupNavPreviousSelector:       '.nav-previous',                // (Advanced) Popup Nav Previous selector
                    popupNavNextSelector:           '.nav-next',                    // (Advanced) Popup Nav Next selector
                    onPopupClose:                   null,                           // On Popup Close Callback
                    onPopupOpen:                    null                            // On Popup Open Callback
            }, options);
            
        // Variables

            var __msie = navigator.userAgent.match(/MSIE ([0-9]+)\./), __msie6 = __msie && (RegExp.$1 == 6), __msie67 = __msie && (RegExp.$1 < 8);
            var __pos = (__msie6 ? 'absolute' : 'fixed');
            var _isTouch = !!('ontouchstart' in window), _eventType = 'click';
            var isLocked = false, cache = new Array();

            var _top = jQuery(this);
            var _body = jQuery('body');
            var _overlay = jQuery('<div></div>');
            var _window = jQuery(window);
            var windowWidth, windowHeight, queue = [], navPos = 0;

            function updateWH()
            {
                windowWidth = jQuery(window).width();
                windowHeight = jQuery(window).height() + settings.windowHeightPad;
            }

            // Disable unused features
                if (!settings.usePopupLoader)
                    settings.popupLoaderSelector = null;

                if (!settings.usePopupCloser)
                    settings.popupCloserSelector = null;

                if (!settings.usePopupCaption)
                    settings.popupCaptionSelector = null;

                if (!settings.usePopupNav)
                {
                    settings.popupNavPreviousSelector = null;
                    settings.popupNavNextSelector = null;
                }

            // Get popup
                if (settings.popupSelector)
                    var _popup = jQuery(settings.popupSelector);
                else
                    var _popup = jQuery('<div class="' + settings.popupClass + '">' + (settings.popupLoaderSelector ? '<div class="loader">' + settings.popupLoaderText + '</div>' : '') + '<div class="pic"></div>' + (settings.popupCaptionSelector ? '<div class="caption"></div>' : '') + (settings.popupCloserSelector ? '<span class="closer">' + settings.popupCloserText + '</span>' : '') + (settings.popupNavPreviousSelector ? '<div class="nav-previous"></div>' : '') + (settings.popupNavNextSelector ? '<div class="nav-next"></div>' : '') + '</div>');

            // Get popup components
                var _pic = _popup.find('.pic');
                var _x = jQuery();
                var _loader = _popup.find(settings.popupLoaderSelector);
                var _caption = _popup.find(settings.popupCaptionSelector);
                var _closer = _popup.find(settings.popupCloserSelector);
                var _nav_next = _popup.find(settings.popupNavNextSelector);
                var _nav_previous = _popup.find(settings.popupNavPreviousSelector);
                var _nav = _nav_next.add(_nav_previous);

            // Apply default styling?
                if (settings.usePopupDefaultStyling)
                {
                    _popup.css('background', settings.popupBackgroundColor);
                    _popup.css('color', settings.popupTextColor);
                    _popup.css('padding', settings.popupPadding + 'px');
                        
                    if (_caption.length > 0)
                    {
                        _popup.css('padding-bottom', settings.popupCaptionHeight + 'px');
                        _caption
                            .css('position', 'absolute')
                            .css('left', '0')
                            .css('bottom', '0')
                            .css('width', '100%')
                            .css('text-align', 'center')
                            .css('height', settings.popupCaptionHeight + 'px')
                            .css('line-height', settings.popupCaptionHeight + 'px');
                            
                        if (settings.popupCaptionTextSize)
                            _caption.css('font-size', popupCaptionTextSize);
                    }
                        
                    if (_closer.length > 0)
                        _closer
                            .html(settings.popupCloserText)
                            .css('font-size', settings.popupCloserTextSize)
                            .css('background', settings.popupCloserBackgroundColor)
                            .css('color', settings.popupCloserTextColor)
                            .css('display', 'block')
                            .css('width', '40px')
                            .css('height', '40px')
                            .css('line-height', '40px')
                            .css('text-align', 'center')
                            .css('position', 'absolute')
                            .css('text-decoration', 'none')
                            .css('outline', '0')
                            .css('top', '0')
                            .css('right', '-40px');
                            
                    if (_loader.length > 0)
                    {
                        _loader
                            .html('')
                            .css('position', 'relative')
                            .css('font-size', settings.popupLoaderTextSize)
                            .bind('startSpinning', function(e) {
                                var x = jQuery('<div>' + settings.popupLoaderText + '</div>');
                                x
                                    .css('height', Math.floor(settings.popupHeight / 2) + 'px')
                                    .css('overflow', 'hidden')
                                    .css('line-height', Math.floor(settings.popupHeight / 2) + 'px')
                                    .css('text-align', 'center')
                                    .css('margin-top', Math.floor((_popup.height() - x.height() + (_caption.length > 0 ? _caption.height() : 0)) / 2))
                                    .css('color', (settings.popupTextColor ? settings.popupTextColor : ''))
                                    .bind('xfin', function() { x.fadeTo(300, 0.5, function() { x.trigger('xfout'); }); })
                                    .bind('xfout', function() { x.fadeTo(300, 0.05, function() { x.trigger('xfin'); }); })
                                    .trigger('xfin');
                                _loader.append(x);
                            })
                            .bind('stopSpinning', function(e) {
                                var x = _loader.find('div');
                                x.remove();
                            });
                    }
                    
                    if (_nav.length == 2)
                    {
                        _nav
                            .css('font-size', '75px')
                            .css('text-align', 'center')
                            .css('color', '#fff')
                            .css('text-shadow', 'none')
                            .css('height', '100%')
                            .css('position', 'absolute')
                            .css('top', '0')
                            .css('opacity', '0.35')
                            .css('cursor', 'pointer')
                            .css('box-shadow', 'inset 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0)')
                            .poptrox_disableSelection();

                        var wn, wp;

                        if (settings.usePopupEasyClose)
                        {
                            wn = '100px';
                            wp = '100px';
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            wn = '75%';
                            wp = '25%';
                        }
                        
                        _nav_next
                            .css('right', '0')
                            .css('width', wn)
                            .html('<div style="position: absolute; height: 100px; width: 125px; top: 50%; right: 0; margin-top: -50px;">&gt;</div>');

                        _nav_previous
                            .css('left', '0')
                            .css('width', wp)
                            .html('<div style="position: absolute; height: 100px; width: 125px; top: 50%; left: 0; margin-top: -50px;">&lt;</div>');
                    }
                }
        
        // Main
            _window
                .bind('orientationchange', function() {
                    _window.trigger('resize');
                })
                .resize(function() {
                    updateWH();
                    _popup.trigger('poptrox_close');
                });

            _caption
                .bind('update', function(e, s) {
                    if (!s || s.length == 0)
                        s = settings.popupBlankCaptionText;
                    _caption.html(s);
                });
            
            _closer
                .css('cursor', 'pointer')
                .bind(_eventType, function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    e.stopPropagation();
                    _popup.trigger('poptrox_close');
                    return true;
                });

            _nav_next
                .click(function() {
                    _popup.trigger('poptrox_next');
                });

            _nav_previous
                .click(function() {
                    _popup.trigger('poptrox_previous');
                });

            _overlay
                .prependTo(__msie67 ? 'body' : 'html')
                .hide();

            if (__msie6)
                _overlay.css('position', 'absolute');
            else
                _overlay
                    .css('position', __pos)
                    .css('left', 0)
                    .css('top', 0)
                    .css('z-index', settings.baseZIndex)
                    .css('width', '200%')
                    .css('height', '200%')
                    .css('background-color', settings.overlayColor);

            _overlay
                .css('cursor', 'pointer')
                .bind(_eventType, function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    e.stopPropagation();
                    _popup.trigger('poptrox_close');
                });

            if (settings.usePopupEasyClose)
            {
                _pic
                    .css('cursor', 'pointer')
                    .bind(_eventType, function(e) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        e.stopPropagation();
                        _popup.trigger('poptrox_close');
                    });
            }

            _popup
                .bind('poptrox_next', function() {
                    var x = navPos + 1;
                    if (x >= queue.length)
                        x = 0;
                    _popup.trigger('poptrox_switch', [x]);
                })
                .bind('poptrox_previous', function() {
                    var x = navPos - 1;
                    if (x < 0)
                        x = queue.length - 1;
                    _popup.trigger('poptrox_switch', [x]);
                })
                .bind('poptrox_reset', function() {
                    updateWH();

                    _popup
                        .css('position', __pos)
                        .css('z-index', settings.baseZIndex + 1)
                        .css('width', settings.popupWidth + 'px')
                        .css('height', settings.popupHeight + 'px')
                        .css('left', (windowWidth / 2) + 'px')
                        .css('top', (windowHeight / 2) + 'px')
                        .css('top', (windowHeight / 2) + 'px')
                        .css('margin-left', (-1 * (_popup.outerWidth() / 2)) + 'px')
                        .css('margin-top', (-1 * (_popup.outerHeight() / 2)) + 'px')
                    _loader.hide().trigger('stopSpinning');
                    _caption.hide();
                    _closer.hide();
                    _nav.hide();
                    _pic.hide();
                    _x.detach();
                })
                .bind('poptrox_open', function(e, index) {
                    if (isLocked)
                        return true;
                    isLocked = true;
                    if (settings.useBodyOverflow)
                        _body.css('overflow', 'hidden');
                    if (settings.onPopupOpen)
                        (settings.onPopupOpen)();
                    _overlay
                        .fadeTo(settings.fadeSpeed, settings.overlayOpacity, function() {
                            _popup.trigger('poptrox_switch', [index, true]);
                        });
                })
                .bind('poptrox_switch', function(e, index, ignoreLock) {
                    var x, img;

                    if (!ignoreLock && isLocked)
                        return true;
                    
                    isLocked = true;

                    // Cleanup from previous
                        _caption.hide();
                        if (_x.attr('src'))
                            _x.attr('src', '');
                        _x.detach();
                    
                    // Activate new object
                        x = queue[index];
                        _x = x.object;
                        _x.unbind('load');
                    
                        _pic
                            .css('text-indent', '-9999em')
                            .show()
                            .append(_x);

                        if (x.type == 'ajax')
                        {
                            jQuery.get(x.src, function(data) {
                                _x.html(data);
                                _x.trigger('load');
                            });
                        }
                        else
                            _x.attr('src', x.src);
                        
                        if (x.type != 'image')
                            _x
                                .css('position', 'relative')
                                .css('outline', '0')
                                .css('z-index', settings.baseZIndex + 100)
                                .width(x.width)
                                .height(x.height);

                    // Initialize
                        _loader.trigger('startSpinning').fadeIn(300);
                        _popup.show();

                    if (settings.popupIsFixed)
                    {
                        _popup
                            .width(settings.popupWidth)
                            .height(settings.popupHeight)
                            .css('margin-left', (-1 * (_popup.innerWidth() / 2)) + 'px')
                            .css('margin-top', (-1 * (_popup.innerHeight() / 2)) + 'px');

                        _x.load(function() {
                            _x.unbind('load');
                            _loader.hide().trigger('stopSpinning');
                            _caption.trigger('update', [x.captionText]).fadeIn(settings.fadeSpeed);
                            _closer.fadeIn(settings.fadeSpeed);
                            _pic.css('text-indent', 0).hide().fadeIn(settings.fadeSpeed, function() { isLocked = false; });
                            navPos = index;
                            _nav.fadeIn(settings.fadeSpeed);
                        });
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        _x.load(function() {
                            _x.unbind('load');

                            updateWH();

                            var dw = Math.abs(_popup.width() - _popup.outerWidth()), dh = Math.abs(_popup.height() - _popup.outerHeight());
                            var nw = _x.width(), nh = _x.height();
                            var maxw = windowWidth - (settings.windowMargin * 2) - dw, maxh = windowHeight - (settings.windowMargin * 2) - dh;
                            
                            _loader.hide().trigger('stopSpinning');
                            
                            if (nw > maxw || nh > maxh)
                            {
                                var multW, multH, m;
                                
                                multW = maxw / nw;
                                multH = maxh / nh;
                                m = Math.min(multW, multH);
                                
                                nw = Math.floor(m * nw);
                                nh = Math.floor(m * nh);

                                _x.width(nw).height(nh);
                            }

                            if (_popup.innerWidth() == nw + dw
                            &&  _popup.innerHeight() == nh + dh)
                            {
                                _caption.trigger('update', [x.captionText]).fadeIn(settings.fadeSpeed);
                                _closer.fadeIn(settings.fadeSpeed);
                                _pic.css('text-indent', 0).hide().fadeIn(settings.fadeSpeed, function() { isLocked = false; });
                                navPos = index;
                            }
                            else
                                _popup
                                    .animate({
                                        width: nw,
                                        height: nh,
                                        marginLeft: (-1 * (nw / 2)) - (dw / 2),
                                        marginTop: (-1 * (nh / 2)) - (dh / 2)
                                    }, settings.popupSpeed, 'swing', function() {
                                        _caption.trigger('update', [x.captionText]).fadeIn(settings.fadeSpeed);
                                        _closer.fadeIn(settings.fadeSpeed);
                                        _pic.css('text-indent', 0).hide().fadeIn(settings.fadeSpeed, function() { isLocked = false; });
                                        navPos = index;
                                        _nav.fadeIn(settings.fadeSpeed);
                                    });
                        });
                    }
                    
                    if (x.type != 'image')
                        _x.trigger('load');
                })
                .bind('poptrox_close', function() {
                    if (isLocked)
                        return true;
                    isLocked = true;
                    _popup
                        .hide()
                        .trigger('poptrox_reset');
                    if (settings.onPopupClose)
                        (settings.onPopupClose)();
                    _overlay
                        .fadeOut(settings.fadeSpeed, function() {
                            if (settings.useBodyOverflow)
                                _body.css('overflow', 'auto');
                            isLocked = false;
                        });
                })
                .prependTo('body')
                .hide()
                .trigger('poptrox_reset');

            _window
                .keydown(function(e) {
                    if (_popup.is(':visible'))
                    {
                        switch (e.keyCode)
                        {
                            case 37:
                            case 32:
                                if (settings.usePopupNav)
                                {
                                    _popup.trigger('poptrox_previous');
                                    return false;
                                }
                                break;

                            case 39:
                                if (settings.usePopupNav)
                                {
                                    _popup.trigger('poptrox_next');
                                    return false;
                                }
                                break;

                            case 27:
                                _popup.trigger('poptrox_close');
                                return false;

                                break;
                        }
                    }
                });
            
            _top.find(settings.selector).each(function(index) {
                
                var x, tmp, a = jQuery(this), i = a.find('img'), data = a.data('poptrox');

                x = {
                    src:            a.attr('href'),
                    captionText:    i.attr('title'),
                    width:          a.attr('width'),
                    height:         a.attr('height'),
                    type:           null,
                    object:         null
                };

                // If a data attribute exists, use it
                    if (data)
                    {
                        var k, b = data.split(',');
                        
                        for (k in b)
                        {
                            tmp = b[k].match(/([0-9]+)x([0-9]+)/);
                            
                            // Size
                                if (tmp && tmp.length == 3)
                                {
                                    x.width = tmp[1];
                                    x.height = tmp[2];
                                }
                            // Type
                                else
                                    x.type = b[k];
                        }
                    }
                    
                // No type? Attempt to guess it based on the href's domain
                    if (!x.type)
                    {
                        tmp = x.src.match(/http[s]?:\/\/([a-z0-9\.]+)\/.*/);

                        if (!tmp || tmp.length < 3)
                            tmp = [false];

                        switch (tmp[1])
                        {
                            case 'api.soundcloud.com':
                                x.type = 'soundcloud';
                                break;

                            case 'youtu.be':
                                x.type = 'youtube';
                                break;

                            case 'vimeo.com':
                                x.type = 'vimeo';
                                break;

                            default:
                                x.type = 'image';
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                
                // Create object (based on type)
                    tmp = x.src.match(/http[s]?:\/\/[a-z0-9\.]+\/(.*)/);

                    switch (x.type)
                    {
                        case 'ignore':
                            break;
                    
                        case 'iframe':
                            x.object = jQuery('<iframe src="" frameborder="0"></iframe>');
                            x.object
                                .bind(_eventType, function(e) { e.stopPropagation(); })
                                .css('cursor', 'auto');
                            break;
                            
                        case 'ajax':
                            x.object = jQuery('<div class="poptrox-ajax"></div>');
                            x.object
                                .bind(_eventType, function(e) { e.stopPropagation(); })
                                .css('cursor', 'auto')
                                .css('overflow', 'auto');
                            break;
                    
                        case 'soundcloud':
                            x.object = jQuery('<iframe scrolling="no" frameborder="no" src=""></iframe>');
                            x.src = 'https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=' + escape(x.src);
                            x.width = '600';
                            x.height = "166";
                            break;

                        case 'youtube':
                            x.object = jQuery('<iframe src="" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="1"></iframe>');
                            x.src = 'http://www.youtube.com/embed/' + tmp[1];
                            break;

                        case 'vimeo':
                            x.object = jQuery('<iframe src="" frameborder="0" allowFullScreen="1"></iframe>');
                            x.src = 'http://player.vimeo.com/video/' + tmp[1];
                            break;

                        default:
                            x.object = jQuery('<img src="" alt="" />');
                            if (settings.preload) { var tmp = document.createElement('img'); tmp.src = x.src; cache.push(tmp); }
                            break;
                    }

                queue.push(x);
                
                i
                    .attr('title', '');
                
                if (x.type != 'ignore')
                {
                    a
                        .attr('href', '')
                        .css('outline', 0)
                        .click(function(e) {
                            e.preventDefault();
                            e.stopPropagation();
                            _popup.trigger('poptrox_open', [index]);
                        });
                }
            });
            
        return jQuery(this);
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Where is the `</nav>`

Comment: Thanks. I'm sure this would work great but the contact info appears to be in a different line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- What you're trying to achieve requires you to apply
  `position: fixed` to both elements. Another better approach is to
  only apply `position: fixed` to the parent `nav` element.
- For making it change color on scroll, requires javascript. I've added the code in the demo. Also, added a transition to it. The default nav is absolute but as the scroll reaches nav height it becomes fixed and changes in color.
- I also noticed you were using `floating` but not clearing the float.
  It's better to just use `display: flex`. I have wrapped the inner nav elements inside `.nav-inner` and applied flex to it for better control.
- Your code is also missing the closing tags for `nav`, `body`, and `html`.

**Demo:**

```js
let nav = document.getElementById('nav');

window.addEventListener('scroll', function () {
    if (window.pageYOffset > nav.offsetHeight) {
        nav.classList.add('sticky');
    } else {
        nav.classList.remove('sticky');
    }
});
```

```css
body {
    height: 2000px;
    /* For demo only */
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
}

nav {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
    transition: all 0.2s ease;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.inner-nav {
    padding: 50px;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
        -ms-flex-align: center;
            align-items: center;
    -webkit-box-pack: justify;
        -ms-flex-pack: justify;
            justify-content: space-between;
}

#menuToggle {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
#menuToggle a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #232323;
    -webkit-transition: color 0.3s ease;
    transition: color 0.3s ease;
}
#menuToggle a:hover {
    color: yellowgreen;
}
#menuToggle input {
    display: block;
    width: 40px;
    height: 32px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -7px;
    left: -5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 2;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
}
#menuToggle span {
    display: block;
    width: 33px;
    height: 4px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    position: relative;
    background: #cdcdcd;
    border-radius: 3px;
    z-index: 1;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 4px 0px;
            transform-origin: 4px 0px;
    -webkit-transition: background 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0.2, 0.05, 1), opacity 0.55s ease, -webkit-transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0.2, 0.05, 1);
    transition: background 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0.2, 0.05, 1), opacity 0.55s ease, -webkit-transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0.2, 0.05, 1);
    transition: transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0.2, 0.05, 1), background 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0.2, 0.05, 1), opacity 0.55s ease;
    transition: transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0.2, 0.05, 1), background 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0.2, 0.05, 1), opacity 0.55s ease, -webkit-transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0.2, 0.05, 1);
}
#menuToggle span:first-child {
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0% 0%;
            transform-origin: 0% 0%;
}
#menuToggle span:nth-last-child(2) {
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0% 100%;
            transform-origin: 0% 100%;
}
#menuToggle input:checked ~ span {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-2px, -1px);
            transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-2px, -1px);
    background: #232323;
}
#menuToggle input:checked ~ span:nth-last-child(3) {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg) scale(0.2, 0.2);
            transform: rotate(0deg) scale(0.2, 0.2);
}
#menuToggle input:checked ~ span:nth-last-child(2) {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(0, -1px);
            transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(0, -1px);
}
#menuToggle input:checked ~ ul {
    -webkit-transform: none;
            transform: none;
}

#menu {
    position: absolute;
    width: 300px;
    margin: -100px 0 0 -50px;
    padding: 50px;
    padding-top: 125px;
    padding-bottom: 325px;
    background: #ededed;
    list-style-type: none;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0% 0%;
            transform-origin: 0% 0%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-100%, 0);
            transform: translate(-100%, 0);
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0.2, 0.05, 1);
    transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0.2, 0.05, 1);
    transition: transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0.2, 0.05, 1);
    transition: transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0.2, 0.05, 1), -webkit-transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0.2, 0.05, 1);
}
#menu li {
    padding: 8px 0;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.header-right ul {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.header-right li {
    margin-left: 50px;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
    transition: 0.5s;
}
.header-right li i {
    margin-right: 7px;
    color: #888;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.header-right li:hover {
    color: #7370d8;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.subscribe-form input[type=text] {
    padding: 13.225px 30px;
    border: none;
    background: #f2f2f2;
}
.subscribe-form input[type=submit] {
    background: #9bf55f;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 16px 24px;
    border: none;
    font-size: 18px;
}

.sticky {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    background: #232323;
    color: #cdcdcd;
}
.sticky a {
    color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My website</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
        <!--[if lte IE 8]>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
            <script src="css/ie/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
        <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.poptrox-2.2.js"></script>
        <noscript>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/skel-noscript.css" />
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
        </noscript>
        <!--[if lte IE 8]>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ie/v8.css" />
        <![endif]-->
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav id="nav" role="navigation">
            <div class="inner-nav">
                <div id="menuToggle">
                    <input type="checkbox" />

                    <span></span>
                    <span></span>
                    <span></span>

                    <ul id="menu">
                        <a href="index.html">
                            <li>Home</li>
                        </a>
                        <a href="about-us.html">
                            <li>My listings</li>
                        </a>
                        <a href="https://selar.co/vmo2" target="_blank">
                            <li>Bookings</li>
                        </a>
                        <a href="faq.html">
                            <li>FAQ</li>
                        </a>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="header-right">
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#"> <i class="fa fa-phone"></i> +5558976555 </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#"> <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>mylistings@gmail.com </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Updated 2/28/2022:**

- Fixed menu toggle - reason was z-index not applying. Added `position: relative` to `#menuToggle`
- Removed underlines from links
- Cleaned-up code. Removed floating and using flex.
- Added vendor-prefixes in css

Comment: Thanks, this almost works perfectly. Only thing, the hamburger isn't toggling any longer.

Comment: Thanks also for the helpful comments pointing out what I was doing wrong. How can I get the hamburger to toggle again? I'm going through your cleaned up code and it isn't apparent to my amateur eyes what the problem is.

Comment: So, I realised that you have to click up above the menu hamburger to get the pointer and be able to click and toggle the hamburger. What could be wrong there> Also the underline under the contact info, don't want that. I've tried all the skills in my arsenal. Sorry, newbie editing a template and many thanks.

Comment: The hamburger wasn’t toggling before either as you didn’t share any JavaScript code. You’ll need to share the complete code for that. Regarding underline links, that wasn’t part of your original question, but to fix use this css: 

a { text-decoration: none; }

Comment: Hi, @Arslan Akram, thanks. I already did  { text-decoration: none; } for the underline links but it didn't work. I'll add the js code to the question now.

Comment: By the way, the {background} in this code is flagged in red in my code editor. Just in case that's a clue        {transition: transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0.2, 0.05, 1.0),
   background 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0.2, 0.05, 1.0),
   opacity 0.55s ease;}

Comment: Fixed the hamburger. Reason was z-index not applying. Added `position: relative` to `#menuToggle`. Also cleaned up the code. See my updated answer above.

Comment: Thanks so much. It should be good now.

Answer (score 1):

You are so close to the solution. I really appreciate you for that.

I have deployed the code to the dummy URL:
https://distracted-pasteur-66c13a.netlify.app/

You can use the following CSS to make your navbar sticky.

```
 nav {

       /* to give background color */
       background: #232323;
       /* to give the text color */
       color: #cdcdcd;
       /* to make the nav fixed */
       position: fixed;
       /* to set the position of the navbar */
       top: 0;
       /* to set the width of navbar */
       width: 100%;
       /* to make it look cleaner */
       padding-bottom: 30px;
     }
```

I have updated your code and it is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
    <style>
        nav {
            /* to give background color */
            background: #232323;
            /* to give the text color */
            color: #cdcdcd;
            /* to make the nav fixed */
            position: fixed;
            /* to set the position of the navbar */
            top: 0;
            /* to set the width of navbar */
            width: 100%;
            /* to make it look cleaner */
            padding-bottom: 30px;
        }

        #menuToggle {
            display: inline-block;
            position: fixed;
            top: 50px;
            left: 50px;

            z-index: 1;

            -webkit-user-select: none;
            user-select: none;
        }

        #menuToggle a {
            text-decoration: none;
            color: #232323;

            transition: color 0.3s ease;
        }

        #menuToggle a:hover {
            color: yellowgreen;
        }


        #menuToggle input {
            display: block;
            width: 40px;
            height: 32px;
            position: absolute;
            top: -7px;
            left: -5px;

            cursor: pointer;

            opacity: 0;
            /* hide this */
            z-index: 2;
            /* and place it over the hamburger */

            -webkit-touch-callout: none;
        }

        /*
        * Just a quick hamburger
        */
        #menuToggle span {
            display: block;
            width: 33px;
            height: 4px;
            margin-bottom: 5px;
            position: relative;

            background: #cdcdcd;
            border-radius: 3px;

            z-index: 1;

            transform-origin: 4px 0px;

            transition: transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0.2, 0.05, 1.0),
                background 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0.2, 0.05, 1.0),
                opacity 0.55s ease;
        }

        #menuToggle span:first-child {
            transform-origin: 0% 0%;
        }

        #menuToggle span:nth-last-child(2) {
            transform-origin: 0% 100%;
        }

        /*
        * Transform all the slices of hamburger
        * into a crossmark.
        */
        #menuToggle input:checked~span {
            opacity: 1;
            transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-2px, -1px);
            background: #232323;
        }

        /*
        * But let's hide the middle one.
        */
        #menuToggle input:checked~span:nth-last-child(3) {
            opacity: 0;
            transform: rotate(0deg) scale(0.2, 0.2);
        }

        /*
        * Ohyeah and the last one should go the other direction
        */
        #menuToggle input:checked~span:nth-last-child(2) {
            transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(0, -1px);
        }

        /*
        * Make this absolute positioned
        * at the top left of the screen
        */
        #menu {
            position: absolute;
            width: 300px;
            margin: -100px 0 0 -50px;
            padding: 50px;
            padding-top: 125px;
            padding-bottom: 325px;

            background: #ededed;
            list-style-type: none;
            -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
            /* to stop flickering of text in safari */

            transform-origin: 0% 0%;
            transform: translate(-100%, 0);

            transition: transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0.2, 0.05, 1.0);
        }

        #menu li {
            padding: 8px 0;
            font-size: 20px;

        }

        /*
        * And let's slide it in from the left
        */
        #menuToggle input:checked~ul {
            transform: none;
        }


        /* header-right */
        .header-right li {
            display: inline-block;
            margin-right: 50px;
            margin-top: 45px;
            font-size: 16px;
            text-decoration: none;
            float: right;
            font-family: inherit;
            -webkit-transition: .5s;
            -moz-transition: .5s;
            -ms-transition: .5s;
            -o-transition: .5s;
            transition: .5s;

        }

        .header-right li i {
            margin-right: 7px;
            color: #888;
            text-decoration: none;
        }

        .header-right li :hover {
            color: #7370d8;
            text-decoration: none;
        }

        /*
        * Subscription form for newsletter
        */

        .subscribe-form input[type="text"] {
            padding: 13.225px 30px;
            border: none;
            background: #f2f2f2;
            float: none;

        }

        .subscribe-form input[type="submit"] {
            background: #9bf55f;
            color: #fff;
            padding: 16px 24px;
            border: none;
            font-size: 18px;
            float: none;

        }

        .vh100 {
            min-height: 100vh;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <nav role="navigation">
        <div id="menuToggle">

            <input type="checkbox" />


            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>


            <ul id="menu">
                <a href="index.html">
                    <li>Home</li>
                </a>
                <a href="about-us.html">
                    <li>My listings</li>
                </a>
                <a href="https://selar.co/vmo2" target="_blank">
                    <li>Bookings</li>
                </a>
                <a href="faq.html">
                    <li>FAQ</li>
                </a>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="header-right">
            <ul class="pull-right">
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <i class="fa fa-phone"></i> +5558976555
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>mylistings@gmail.com
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="vh100" style="background-color: #7370d8;">

    </div>
    <div class="vh100" style="background-color: #303033;">

    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Do let me know if you need more help with this.

Thanks, 
Shubh Wadekar

Comment: I'd tried positon:fixed but nothing worked. But thanks.

Comment: @ladyem I have updated my answer for better understanding. Do let me know if it helps.